# unir dos array basados en un propiedad

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo dos array de esta forma

```
array1=[{fecha:"2017-01-01", valor:12}, {fecha:"2017-01-02", valor:3 }];
array2 = [{fecha:"2017-01-01", valor:10}, {fecha:"2017-01-03", valor:15 }];
```

y quiero formar un tercer array a partir de estos dos almacenando los valores, siempre y cuando la fecha coincida, para que quede la siguiente forma:

```
array3 = [{fecha:"2017-01-01", valor1:12, valor2:10}, {fecha:"2017-01-02", valor1:3, valor2:0}];
```

He intentado hacerlo de esta manera :

```
for (var j in array1.rows){
    var param = array1.rows[j].key;
    // console.log("disparando");
    // console.log(item.key);
    function locate (array) {
        return array.key =param;
    }
    array3.push({
        "y":param,
        "a":array1.rows[j].value,
         "b":array2.rows.find(locate).value,
        
    });
}
```

pero no consigo el valor sigue siendo el mismo en todo el array, como puedo formar el tercer arrreglo

Comment: Parece que la [tag:nodejs] sale sobrando  ya que no se menciona nada sobre este y el tema no es específico de dicha etiqueta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes concatenar ambos arrays y luego hacer un filtrado dependiendo en la cantidad de ocurrencias de acuerdo al campo en común (fecha). Ya que usas Node.js, puedes aprovechar el poder de ES6.

**Ejemplo**

```js
array1=[{fecha:"2017-01-01", valor:12}, {fecha:"2017-01-02", valor:3 }];
array2 = [{fecha:"2017-01-01", valor:10}, {fecha:"2017-01-03", valor:15 }];

const finalArray = 
  array1
    .concat(array2)
    .map((el, i, self) => {
      const existences = self.filter(obj => obj.fecha === el.fecha);
      if (existences.length > 1) {
        const $el = Object.assign({}, el, {
         valor: existences.map(obj => obj.valor)
        });
        return $el;
      }
    })
    .filter((el, i, self) => el)
    .filter((el, i, self) => (
      self.findIndex($el => $el.fecha === el.fecha) === i
    ));

console.dir(finalArray);
```

---

**PD:** En lugar de *valor1*, *valor2*, *valorn*, etc., los he agrupado como un array para que estén mejor organizados.

Answer (score 2):

Algo como esto te debería de valer; **no lo he probado**, pero, salvo cambios mínimos, debería de funcionar:

```
function MergeArrays( key, val ) {
  var curr,
      idx,
      gcurr,
      gidx = 1,
      ret = [ ];

  while( gcurr = arguments[++gidx] ) {
    idx = -1;

    while( curr = gcurr[++idx] )
      if( curr[key] == val )
        ret.push( curr );
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Su uso es muy simple: MergeArrays( key, val, arr1, ... )

- `key` -> nombre de la propiedad a comparar.
- `val` -> valor a buscar.
- arr1, ... -> 1 o mas arrays de objetos.

En el caso que expones, sería:

```
newArray = MergeArrays( "fecha", "2017-01-01", array1, array2 );
```